# Android Emulator Browser - Background Images Missing

Tags: android, css, background-image

I want to test a web-app in android, so I launched the emulator through eclipse. For some reason, I'm not seeing any of the background images. They come through fine in all regular desktop browsers and in iOS.

Is this a flaw in the android emulator? Is it fixable? Should I be concerned about actual android display?

Comment: If you could share a sample of your code it'd be helpful in trying to track down an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that android doesn't display base64 encoded bg images in css.